# Java http server and web folder

Tags: java, php, web, directory, httpserver

does anyone know how to create HTTP server in Java, but set default folder for web and than load files from it? I want to use `com.sun.net.httpserver` class.

For example, I have folder named *abc* next to my java file. The java file runs HTTP server under port 8080. And if I open address `http://123.123.123.123:8080/` I want to see list of files from folder *abc*. In folder abc are some files, eg. *image.jpg*. So I want to open in my browser address to image file, like `http://123.123.123.123:8080/image.jpg`. This way I can open all other files from folder *abc* (also subfolders, files in subfolders etc.).

1. Is it possible to create this HTTP server?
2. Would it be somehow possible to run PHP files in the folder?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using embedded Jetty? I am pretty sure that with it you can accomplish what you are looking for.
If you want to execute PHP from within Jetty, refer to http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+and+PHP

Comment: But on my server machine isn't Apache installed. Will the PHP still work?

Comment: Does not really matter. PHP must be installed (5 or higher and some scripting environment). Read the docs for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created your server object, you need to register some handlers for the path you want the user to use to fetch documents.

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("localhost",8080));
HttpHandler myDocsHandler = new MyDocsHandler();
server.createContext("/abc", myDocsHandler);
```

There are no built in default handlers, so you will need to write the **MyDocsHandler** class that implements the **HttpHandler** interface to handle any requests coming into your server at **http://localhost:8080/abc**.

The handler requires a single **handle** method that takes an **HttpExchange** argument that gives access to the request data and the response stream.  It is your responsibility at this point to do what needs doing.  So if you wanted the actual files to be located on your hard driver at **/usr/local/abc** your handler would need to open the requested file using standard file io and stream it back to the user.